# Result set BAR chart order by(sorting)

Tags: maximo

I would like to know are there any way to sorting the BAR chart in the result set? (ex. order by count)

Columns are unordered in random order.

In Ex. system properities, xml etc.?

Maximo (7.6.0.9)

Comment: What is your database? Did you using `order by` at the end your where clause in the saved query? Can you provide a screenshot of what you are currently getting and what'd you like for it look like?

Comment: Oracle database. Yes I use "order by" in the query. There is the picture [link] (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/ajax/download?nodeId=0431f32a-29ee-423e-8baa-50951d060b5b) Let the first BAR is the biggest, and at the end is the smallest! Currently not in order (by Count)